# Drawing "Stenciled" Sprites and making them glow

Tags: xna, c#, rendering, lighting

Currently, in my game - I'm not using XNA's SpriteBatch to render anything(I am using Farseer Physic's Debug View), and I was wondering how I would render something like this:

[image]

only using XNA. My second question is once I have drawn these stenciled sprites , how would I give the "stenciled" lines a glow effect like so:

[image]

I haven't done anything like this before so It is a very confusing experience for me. Any pointers?

Comment: The general technique for [glow](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch21.html) is here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the line drawing in Farseer's samples is too thin, you could use something like [this library](http://roundline.codeplex.com/) to draw thick lines.

For the glow effect, check out the [XNA Bloom Sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/bloom).

The basic process is to render your scene to a render target. Then render the render-target to the screen twice: once normally and once with a blur effect using additive blending.

Comment: To anyone wondering which library to use to achieve the stenciled sprites I used this library http://jcpmcdonald.com/index.php/2d-xna-primitives
Very easy to use and well documented.